# Cast result from left join to boolean in postgres with django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, left-join, django-queryset

The scene:

I have three models in this way:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ....

class Affiliate(models.Model):
     persona = models.OneToOneField('Person', primary_key=True, db_column='id', parent_link=True, related_name='afiliado')
     ...

class Referred(models.Model):
     persona = models.OneToOneField('Person', primary_key=True, db_column='id', parent_link=True, related_name='referido')
     ...
```

**I need to serialise some query in which I can say if the person is an affiliate or a referred.**

In my first attempt, I build something like:

```
 Person.objects.all().values_list('afiliado__pk') #this is because of the related_name in the relation
```

that throws this SQL:

```
 SELECT `afiliado`.`id` FROM `persona` LEFT OUTER JOIN `afiliado` ON (`persona`.`id` = `afiliado`.`id`)
```

The result is:

```
[(None,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,), (11,), (12,), (13,), (14,), (15,), (16,), (17,), (18,), (19,), (20,), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

**I would like something like:**

```
[(False,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), (True,), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

False if the result of the lef join is null, True if the result of the left join is the id of the record.

Besides, I tried something like:

qs = Persona.objects.all().extra(select={'es_afiliado':"cast(`afiliado`.`id` as boolean)"}).values_list('es_afiliado','afiliado__pk')

But I got this error:

```
DatabaseError: syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: SELECT (cast(`afiliado`.`id` as boolean)) AS "es_afiliado", ...
```

So, if you guys, know any way to get this through django, or even using extra or at least the plain SQL sentency in postgres would be great.

Comment: Is this really Postgresql? the I see ` as identifier quote while Postgresql uses `"`. Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: BTW `SELECT afiliado.id IS NOT NULL ...` - the query you are seeking.

Comment: That is the query that django generates. And the SQL that you give doesn´t work for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to cast your output to boolean.
Your query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(afiliado::boolean, false), COALESCE(id::boolean, false) 
FROM `persona` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `afiliado` ON (`persona`.`id` = `afiliado`.`id`);
```